# Is it more efficient to unset an object properties in destructor?

Tags: php, performance, destructor

Assume a object that has properties with big amount of data, Is it more efficient to unset properties in destructor? or let php free the allocated memory by that object?

```
class A {
    protected $foo;
    protected $bar;
    protected $baz;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->foo = big_amount_of_data();
        $this->bar = reference_to_a_big_object();
        $this->foo = data_from_big_file();
    }

    public function doProcess()
    {
        // do something
    }

    public function __destruct()
    {
        // Should I do this?
        unset(
            $this->foo,
            $this->bar,
            $this->baz
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you some example codes to show what you mean ?

Comment: show your current working code !!!

Comment: @VIVEK-MDU, actually this is what I'm just thinking about and I don't have a working code, but I updated my question with an example code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so to make it simple : No, you shouldn't really do that.

You'd better let PHP do what it wants with your object and its variables when you destruct it if it's all about unsetting variables to get back some memory.

1) You're never sure that unsetting variables with `unset` will give you back the used memory directly. It could be instant (and still, not really, it just depends on when the garbage collector will decide to do his job), it could be a few time later or at the very end of your script anyway thanks to the garbage collector. It's not a sure way to get the memory back, that's it.

2) There will be no change on variables accessibility

Answer (score 2):

Assigning null is better than unsetting. It's faster and in case there are other variables referencing the ones you are unsetting, assigning null will actually free the memory, while unsetting won't - the other variables will still have the data and not null value